# I want to extract the rgb value of the pixel of the image where I click but whenever I click on it. It crashes even though all the syntax is right

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

```
package com.example.camdetect;  

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import com.skydoves.colorpickerview.ColorEnvelope;
import com.skydoves.colorpickerview.ColorPickerView;
import com.skydoves.colorpickerview.listeners.ColorListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int[] s = new int [4];
    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private TextView i_b,i_g,i_r,p_r,p_g,p_b;//**these are declared globally to avoid declaring it final**

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         i_b = this.findViewById(R.id.i_b);
         i_g = this.findViewById(R.id.i_g);
         i_r = this.findViewById(R.id.i_r);
         p_r = this.findViewById(R.id.p_r);
         p_g = this.findViewById(R.id.p_g);
         p_b = this.findViewById(R.id.p_b);

        ColorPickerView colorPickerView = findViewById(R.id.colorPickerView);
        imageview = this.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
```

> pallet to select the color

```
        colorPickerView.setColorListener(new ColorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onColorSelected(int color, boolean fromUser) {

                ColorEnvelope colorenvelope = new ColorEnvelope(color);
                int c[] = colorenvelope.getArgb();
                p_r.setText(String.valueOf(c[1]));
                p_g.setText(String.valueOf(c[2]));
                p_b.setText(String.valueOf(c[3]));
                for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                    s[i] = c[i];
                }

            }

        });
```

> the image i fetched now on touching it will give rgb value of that position i have also tried onclicklistner but not working ,if I give the value of x and y 0 by myself in code then it works fine  all the other portions are fine i think the problem is in the getting the value of  x and y

```
        imageview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int[] viewCoords = new int[2];
                imageview.getLocationOnScreen(viewCoords);
                int x = Math.round(event.getX());
                int y = Math.round(event.getY());
                int imageX = x- viewCoords[0];
                int imageY = y - viewCoords[1];
                ImageView image = ((ImageView)v);
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(imageX,imageY);
                int r,g,b;
                r = Color.red(pixel);
                g = Color.green(pixel);
                b = Color.blue(pixel);
                i_r.setText(String.valueOf(r));
                i_g.setText(String.valueOf(g));
                i_b.setText(String.valueOf(b));
                if(s[1] == r && s[2] == g && s[3] == b){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Match Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Match Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                return true;
            }
        });
```

> button to open camera

```
        Button opencam = this.findViewById(R.id.opencam);
        opencam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

> fetch the image from the camera

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
            imageview.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What Error/Exception does it throw when crashing?

Comment: it shows CamDetect(myappname) has stopped

Comment: there has to be a stacktrace somewhere. have you debugged your code?

Comment: I have added the breakpoints to debug the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: _"I have added the breakpoints to debug the code"_ And what did debugging the code step by step reveal?

Comment: You will find stack traces in run window which is generally placed at the bottom side. Please find and add the stack trace to the question

Comment: My Stacktrace [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dNVY47ym7d1zt2eW9xnQm1JuCrRmxPACTmn4kPdXkZA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: after debugging my code step by step i found that wherever i touch on the the mage the variable "imageY" is always negetive and but whenever it comes on the line "int r,g,b;" the debugger stops i don't know why?